# Number of summands in a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have read the following statement: $\sum \limits_{k =2^{n}+1}^{2^{n+1}}k$ has $2^{n}$ summands. I would not know how to reason that statement. Is there a theorem/law that would back this claim up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's In general quite simple, if you are summing from $k=a$ to $k=b$ then it is $a-b+1$. because you have $a+1$ summands between $0$ and $a$ and you have $b$ summands which are less than $b$ in index, and thus are not summed.
In your example $2^{n+1}-(2^n+1)+1=2^n$

Comment: Quite intuitive actually. The formula is still helpful, thanks.

Comment: I sort of do not get to $2^{n}$. Would be cool if you could maybe write a few extra steps. (But if not I understand, its time consuming).

Comment: $2^{n+1}-2^n = 2^n(2-1)$

Comment: @DavidP Thanks I now see it. I am having trouble to get from $2^{n+1}+(-2^{n}+(-1))+1$ to $2^{n+1}+(-2^{n})+(-1)+1$. Which law is being used here?

Comment: It is the distributive law, I see that now. My brain must have blacked out for the last hour so... :D

Answer (score 1):

To work out the number of summands in a summation is the same as to work out the number of indexes.

As razivo mentioned, here $2^{n+1}-(2^n+1)+1=2^n$

In case if you still do not understand:

Generally, for any summation $$\Sigma_{k=m}^n f(k) = f(m)+f(m+1)+f(m+2)+...+f(n)$$
It is quite obvious though, but if you want to work out the number of terms(summands) in this expression in a rigorous(very rigorous) way, you can simply suppose $x=n-m$,
so that:
$$\Sigma^{m+x}_{k=m} f(k)=f(m+0)+f(m+1)+f(m+2)+...+f(m+x)$$
(here I used $m+0$ instead of $m$ because it makes it looks even more obvious)

Asking "How many summands are there in the summation $f(m+0)+f(m+1)+f(m+2)...+f(m+x)$" is the same as asking "How many integers are there from $m+0$ to $m+x$"

The answer is quite obvious:
$$(m+x)-(m+0) +1= x+1=n-m+1$$

${\bf\underline{\text{Conclusion}}}$:
$$\text{in the summation } \\\Sigma^n_{k=m} \\\text{there are } s \text{ summands, where } s=\\ n-m+1 $$

Comment: In the conclusion you meant $n-m+1?$ I think? Thanks for the eloberative answer.

Comment: @MathNoob Yes, $n-m+1$, I was using $s$ just because it makes it looks nicer.